# "device not open" - QIODevice

Tags: c++, linux, qt

You see a code sector to open a device with QIODevice :

`

```
void MACH3::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);

    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    QString time = QTime::currentTime().toString();
    QString elde = ui->data->toPlainText();
    QString eldetut = ui->data->toPlainText();
    QByteArray inBytes;
    const char *cStrData;
    inBytes = elde.toUtf8();
    cStrData = inBytes.constData();
    QString qtStrData;
    qtStrData = QString::fromUtf8(cStrData);

    QString gelen = serial->readAll();

    if(gelen.length()>0)
    {
        QString eldetut = ui->data->toPlainText();
        QString time2 = QTime::currentTime().toString();
        ui->data->setText(eldetut+"\n"+time2 + "\n" + "received-> "+gelen + "\n");
    }
}
```

`

Could you check the code above?

As failure message came:

"QIODevice::read (QSerialPort): device not open"

Comment: Well .. check with `strace -e file` to see which file it is trying to open and what error it returns?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the return value of the call to *open()* call according to the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qserialport.html#open

I think the main problem is that you did not specify a  port name in your code (neither via the constructor nor via *setPortName()/setPort()*)

Comment: Thank you, that could be - could you give me an example?